# React Hook Form Skip validations if a field is not required

Tags: reactjs

I have registered an optional text field with several validators. I think the validators should not run if the field is empty, because it's optional, and an empty optional field is by definition valid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do an early return.

```js
{
  validate: {
    lessThan10MB: (files) => {
      if (!files[0]) return true; // return true if no files so that it skips validation

      return files[0]?.size < 10000000 || "Max 10MB";
    }
  }
}
```

Just do the same with `acceptedFormats`.

Comment: Even though it works, this is mixing different concerns. IMO, the `lessThan10MB` validator function should not incorporate the "is required" validator. There must be another way...